HTTP Response Code: 401 When Trying to Fetch Public IP of AWS Instance in Java
I am deploying an AWS stack using CloudFormation. It creates an AWS EC2 instance that runs a Java application. The Java application starts and tries to access the public IP of the AWS EC2 instance. Below is my code:
String EC2_PUBLIC_IP_URL = "http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4";

findCurrentPublicIp(DeploymentType deployment) throws IOException {
    URL publicIpUrl = new URL(EC2_PUBLIC_IP_URL);
    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(publicIpUrl.openStream()))) {
        return reader.readLine(); // The only result of the request will be the public IP on one line
    }
}

My implementation works fine when the region is set to eu-central, but it fails for ap-south with the following exception:
Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]

I am using IMDSv2 (imds-2.20.11.jar). Does the API to fetch AWS EC2 instance public IP change depending on region?

IMDSv2 requires a session token; you appear to be using the v1 style of simple GET requests. No idea why that works in one place an not the other, but it's possible that you haven't required v2 on the instances where it works. Also, it doesn't appear that you're using a library to access the service; your code as shown uses Java core networking.

The default version for the instance metadata service (IMDS) is configurable at the region level.
